# Office Word Add-In Chinese garbled when get html from document body

Tags: office-addins

I am going to display the content of the current word document on Add-in Taskpane, I can achieve this simple task by calling [context.document.body.getHtml()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#gethtml--) from which gets an HTML representation of the body object.

But the chinese characters in this html is garbled which means they represent nothing.

For example：

我爱我的家(I love my family) becomes 辨瀹都(Nobody knows what is this)

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: have you added `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your html template?

Comment: the html is generated by word, and there's <meta charset="UTF-8" /> in side the html